# How to prove that a recursive function is equal to another formula?

Tags: induction, recursion

Define recursively b sub 0 = 1 and for n > 0, let b sub n = 3b sub (n−1) − 1. Prove by
induction the formula holds: b sub n =(3^(n)+1)/2.

I started out with a basis:
Let n=1 
We get that 
2=2

Induction Step:
Assume for a fixed n, n>0, that 3b sub (n-1) -1 = (3^(n)+1)/2
Want to show that if the formula is true for n, it works for n+1.

Where should I go from here? I am not all too familiar with induction proofs involving recursive sequences.

Comment: You could set $a_n=2b_n-1$ and show $a_{n+1}=3a_n$ and $a_0=1$ so $a_n=3^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using the original recursion and the inductive step, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
b_{n+1} & = 3b_{n} - 1 \\
& = 3\left(\frac{3^n + 1}{2}\right) - 1 \\
& = \left(\frac{3^{n+1} + 3}{2}\right) - \frac{2}{2} \\
& = \frac{3^{n+1} + 1}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is the same was you would get from your proposed formula for $n + 1$.